# Memory visibility for an in-order queue

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl

After reading the OpenCL 1.1 standard I still can't grasp whether in-order command queue does guarantee memory visibility for any pair of **commands** (**not only kernels**) according to their enqueueing order.

OpenCL standard 1.1 section **5.11** states:

> If the CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE property of a
>   command-queue is not set, the commands enqueued to a command-queue
>   **execute in order**. For example, if an application calls clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to execute kernel A followed by a
>   clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to execute kernel B, the application **can
>   assume that kernel A finishes first and then kernel B is executed**. If
>   the memory objects output by kernel A are inputs to kernel B then
>   **kernel B will see the correct data in memory objects** produced by execution of kernel A.

What about clEnqueueWriteBuffer (non-blocking) and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel enqueued after, which uses that buffer contents?

AFAIK, 'finishes execution' does not imply that corresponding writes are visible (due to relaxed consistency). For example, section **5.10** states specifically:

> The clEnqueueBarrier command **ensures that all queued commands in
>   command_queue have finished execution** before the next batch of
>   commands can begin execution. The clEnqueueBarrier command **is a
>   synchronization point**.

In other words, should I rely on other 'synchronization points'-related rules (events, etc.), or I get memory synchronization out-of-the-box for all the **commands** in an in-order queue?

Comment: > What about clEnqueueWriteBuffer (non-blocking) and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel enqueued after, which uses that buffer contents?   You do not need any other synchronisation points. All the commands in a queue are guaranteed to be executed in-order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What about clEnqueueWriteBuffer (non-blocking) and
>   clEnqueueNDRangeKernel enqueued after, which uses that buffer
>   contents?

since it is in-order queue, it will first write then run the kernel after it finishes, even if the write is non-blocking.

**clEnqueueBarrier** is device-side synchronization command and is intended to work with out-of-order queues. When you use clFinish(), you make the api wait more for the communication between host and device. Enqueueing barrier is much faster synchronization but on the device side only. When you need to synchronize a queue with another queue and still need a similar sync point, you should use **clEnqueueWaitForEvents** just after(or before) the barrier or simply use only the even waiting(for in-order queue).

For opencl 1.2, **clEnqueueWaitForEvents** and **clEnqueueBarrier** was merged into **clEnqueueBarrierWithWaitList** which lets you both barrier out-of-order queue and synchronize it with other queues or even host-side-raised events.

If there is only single in-order queue, you don't need a barrier and when you need to synchronize with host, you can use clFinish or an event-based synchronization command.

> or I get memory synchronization out-of-the-box for all the commands in
>   an in-order queue?

for only **enqueue** type commands, yes. Enqueue (1 write  + 1 compute  + 1 read)  operations 128 times in an in-order queue, they all will work one after another and complete a 128-step simulation(after they are issued by a flush/finish command) . Commands don't have to be in a specific order for this implicit synchronization. Anything like 1 write + 2 reads + 2 kernels +5 writes +1 read + 1 kernel +15 reads work one after another(2 kernels = 1 kernel + 1kernel).

For non-enqueue type commands such as `clSetKernelArg`, you have to use a synchronization point or do it before all enqueuing of commands.

You can also use enqueued commands themselves as an inter-queue sync point with its eventlist parameter and use the next parameter to get its completion event to be used in another queue(signaling) but its still not a barrier for out-of-order queue.

If a buffer is used for two kernels that are in different queues and they are to write data on that buffer, there must be synchronization between queues unless they are writing on different locations. So you can use 20 kernels working on each 1/20th of a buffer and work in parallel using multiple queues and finally synchronize all queues only in the end using a wait list. If a kernel uses or alters another kernels region concurrently, it is undefined behaviour. Similar process can be done for map/unmap too.

in-order vs out-of-order example:

```
r: read, w: write, c: compute


                    <------------clFinish----------------------->
in-order queue....: rwrwrwcwccwccwrcwccccccwrcwcwrwcwrwccccwrwcrw

out-of-order queue: <--r--><-r-><-c-><-----c-----><-----r-----><w>
                     <---w-------><-------r-----><------c----->
                      <---r---><-----c--------------------><--c->
                       <---w---> 
                     <---c-----> <----w------>
```

and another out-of-order queue with a barrier in the middle:

```
                    <---r---><--w---> | <-----w----> 
                    <---c------>      | <----c---> <----w--->
                       <---c--------> | <------r------->
                     <----w------>    | <----c------->
```

where read/write operations before barrier forced to wait until all commands hit same barrier. Then all remaining ones continue concurrently.

The last exemple shows, memory visibility from "host side" can be acquired by barrier or clfinish. But barrier doesn't inform host that it has finished so you need to query events about the queue. ClFinish blocks until all commands are finished so you don't need to query anything. Both will make host see the most updated memory.

---

Your question is about memory visibility for commands of an in-order queue, so you don't need a synchronization point for them to see each others most-up-to-date-values.

Each kernel execution is also a synchronization point between its work groups so work groups can't know other groups' data until kernel finishes and all data is prepared and becomes visible at the end of kernel execution. So next kernel can use it immediately.

---

I haven't tried to read data **concurrently** from device to host without any synchronization points but it **may** work for some devices that are not caching any data on any cache memory. Even integrated gpus have their dedicated L3 caches so it would need at least a barrier command once in a while, to let the host read some updated(but possibly partially re-updated in-flight) data. Event-based synchronization is faster than clFinish and gives correct memory data for host. Barrier is also faster than clFinish but only usable for device-side sync points.

---

If I understand correctly,

> ```
>  Sync Point   -------------------------    Memory visibility
>
>  in-kernel fence                           in same workitem(and wavefront?)
>  in-kernel local memory barrier            local memory in same workgroup
>  in-kernel global memory barrier           global memory in same workgroup
>  in-kernel atomics                         only other atomics in same kernel
>  enqueued kernel/command                   next kernel/command in same queue
>  enqueued barrier                          following commands in same device
>  enqueued event wait                       host
>  clFinish                                  host
> ```

---

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html

> If the buffer object is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR set in
>   mem_flags, the host_ptr specified in clCreateBuffer is **guaranteed** to
>   **contain the latest bits** in the region being mapped when the
>   clEnqueueMapBuffer command has **completed**; and the pointer value
>   returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer will be derived from the host_ptr
>   specified when the buffer object is created.

and

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBuffer.html

> All commands that use this buffer object or a memory object (buffer or
>   image) created from this buffer object have **finished execution** before
>   the **read command begins** execution.

so it doesn't say anything like a barrier or sync. Completion is just enough.

Comment: Although your explanation is very detailed, it still seems solely an opinion (sorry for that). I hope to get some prooflinks to the standard.

Comment: @parallelgeek I started with a fluid simulation for 300 iterations per second then I asked here about it, found out clFinish is not needed between consecutive commands and reached 700 iterations per second. Then I wrote a C# wrapper using 16 queues working independently from each other with an event based sync at the end of each queue. They all worked for many algorithms from fluid simulation to sorting, from particle movement to string search, many things.These were in opencl 1.2 which has exact same definition about memory visibility with 1.1

Comment: I see that your explanation is based on an experience. It's worth reading in itself, thank you. But that's not enough in my case (writing a parallel code generator).

Comment: Good explanation, but I think his problem was to understand "queues" and "blocking events". If an event is non blocking, it affects the host call, not the order in the queue. A queue always ensures in order if it is in order.

Comment: @DarkZeros: I'm interested in what I can squeeze strictly from the standard.

Comment: In an ordered queue, when something finishes, the previous things queued are already finished. 100% sure. If you want to parallelize use multiples queues, since it is easier to keep things separate.

Comment: To squeeze most, device-specific codes(or at least algorithms) are needed. For example, if nvidia can max out with just 3 queues, amd may need 8 queues. Best thing is benchmarking dynamically to find out. Maybe intel is maxed with just 1 queue. And in a single in-order queue, there is nothing else to do other than enqueueing as many commands as possible before a sync command/host sync api command. Maybe you can merge several kernels into one(not always applicable but faster when can)

Comment: Sorry for such an 'obscure' statement. By 'squeezing' I've meant correctness, not performance. I have to be sure my codegenerator emits correct code (in a 'memory visibility' area).

Comment: @parallelgeek in this screenshot, http://imgur.com/a/LFKyS, 1-pixel wide lines are enqueue commands(opencl host thread), actual queue operations are on the "queue-0" row. In there, data transfer(blue blobs) line doesn't ever overlap any kernel execution(green blobs) in an in-order queue. Also there are warning messages below that say clfinish is redundant synchronization here because it thinks there is only only single device to compute(other device is cpu with assembly) because in-order has implicit steps between consecutive enqueued command issues. also blue blobs never overlap each other

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik: It may seem dumb (I really appreciate your work), but what you show is only an implementation behavior, which may or may not be portable.

Comment: @parallelgeek You are right about "there is no explicit definition saying that a command finishes memory updates before next command starts". But all I can say is, I tried my codes on Intel-igpu, Amd-gpu and have some people try on their Nvidia gpus and they all worked fine.  when Khronos says "a command completed", I take it as: it completes everything including flushing local memory, flushing private registers, flushing L1 cache, flushing iinstruction cache, updating main memory. But in my experience I can only see effects of updating main memory and flushing private registers and local mem.

Answer (score 3):

From the spec:

> **In-order Execution**: Commands are launched in the order they appear in the commandqueue and complete in order. In other words, a prior
>   command on the queue completes before the following command begins.
>   This serializes the execution order of commands in a queue.

In case of in-order queues all commands in a queue executed in order, no extra synchronisation is required.

Comment: To me it looks like that 'command execution' does not necessarily mean that corresponding writes are visible to other commands in a queue.

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik: Thanks again for such a 'deeply buried' subtle remarks, but I really don't like such implications. But, it seems it's all I've got.

Comment: @parallelgeek there are manything like this in opencl. Wavefront optimizations, vectors using simd or not, max number of queues, max number of buffers, even max size of buffers is challenging at times. Atomics needing fence to be sure next instruction bypasses cache or not, .... I think they want us to code extremely simple and  don't speculate much except some basic optimizations such as using local memory, using specific alignments, using gather scatter designs and similar.